# Flutter in-app-purchase Android: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0 error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm currently adding in-app purchase in my Flutter app. I have created a subscription on the Google Play Console and it is displayed on my app. I use Firebase's Cloud Functions as a way to validate users purchases and watch their status changes (canceled subscriptions, renewed subscriptions etc...) and Firebase's Firestore database to store the purchases and associate them with a specific user. When I try to verify a purchase is valid (by checking its availability in the store, checking if everything is fine with the data I send) the function returns false. By following the flow of the function I understood that it won't create new entry to the Firestore DB and that is returns false for that reason.
I get those warnings at the same time and they seem to be the reason for it :

```
W/DynamiteModule(17338): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(17338): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(17338): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I have found similar questions asked here but none of the answers fixed my issue.
I have tried to :

1. Add 'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"' in my AndroidManifest.xml
2. Update my Google Services
3. Check thet I have enough storage left
4. Do a "flutter clean" and uninstall the app from my device before launching the app from Visual Code again.

I really don't know what to try now.

Comment: can you add relevant code ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?